# I have two pivot tables but I want to insert into one when I run a function, how do I do this?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

So, as the title says, I have two pivot tables in my Laravel project (I am still new to Laravel). My project is an Instagram clone and I have made the like function, which uses one of the two pivot tables I made and now I'm trying to make a "Save" function, similar to the actual Instagram app where people can save posts and view them at a later time. The problem is, when I check my tinker and do:

[image]

As you can see, it looks like the likes and saves are using the pivot table for likes, I have not inserted anything into the pivot table for saves yet. Here are my migrations

For likes:

```
Schema::create('post_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And for saves:

```
Schema::create('post_user_saves', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('post_id');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I'm aware that they are literally the same but, just like the Instagram app, a user can like a post without saving it and vice-versa and they can also like and save it at the same time. I want to insert into the post_user_saves when I click a button. Here are pics of my database as well, as you can see the post_user_saves table is empty while post_user is not, meaning that tinker is getting the pivot data from post_user

[image]

[image]

and lastly, here are the codes from my model:

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}

public function saves()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
```

EDIT:
here is my store method for the likes:

```
public function store(Post $post){
    return auth()->user()->likes()->toggle($post->id);
}
```

I don't have the store method for my saves yet but my plan is to make it the same as the one above hence why I need to be able to store to post_user_saves.

Answer (score 0):

If your relationships are correct you can use `attach()` to save to the pivot:

```
auth()->user()->likes()->attach(auth::id(), ['column' => 'value']);
```

The reason your save is updating the same table is because you are pretty much using the exact same relationship so eloquent doesn't know about your post_user_saves table what you would need to do is Create a model `Save()` then **rename** your migration to `save_users` and **update your relationship accordingly.**

Comment: will this work with detaching as well or would I have to check if it exists in the database before I detach? Also, I edited my post with the store method

Comment: Yes it would work, I would suggest reading the documentation

Comment: @Tristan, Updated my answer for you

Comment: I've done the code you gave me as well as tried out toggle() but it still inserts into the post_user table instead of post_user_saves. Any idea how I can target the post_user_saves table instead of post_user?

Comment: Answer updated @Tristan You can also try renaming your table to post_save_users before you create the model, but i think you will need that Save model

Comment: Yep, it looks like this:

    class Saves extends Model
    {
        use HasFactory;
    
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }
    }

Comment: okay, thanks! i'll try out these new stuff right now